# Unable to git clone , Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: git, github

```
git clone https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
```

generates error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

I am using a personal tata photon connection and ubuntu 14.04 LTS , I am new to git and any help is welcome ...

Comment: Check your network connection first

Comment: I tried to ping github.com , its working so connection is ok

Comment: `echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc` use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this a couple of times. I generally try the normal ssh protocol instead of https when this happens.

Comment: I tried ssh and its working , I am wondering why https , http protocol is failing to clone , but it generally works in most systems ?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, there will be a issue with delay in appache resonse due to DNS resolve.

Added line #vi /etc/hosts
209.105.235.6    freeswitch.org